# Can I safely perform assignment to a possibly null property without explicit checks for null?

Tags: c#

Given code like:

```
a.b.c = 12;
```

Is there a way to use operators like `?.` and `??` to safely handle the case that `a` or `b` is `null`, and do nothing in that case. `a?.b?.c = 12` gives a compiler error, presumably because the L-value might be null and you cannot assign to null.

I'm using C# 7.3 so `??=` operator is not available but even if it was, I don't think that is the solution. Is it possible or must I do explicit checks?

Comment: So you want 12 to be stored in a, b or c, whichever is first non null?

Comment: No I want it to be stored as per my original expression, but to do nothing in case `a` or `b` is null

Comment: Ah OK, with you now. The problem is that `?.` returns a value and you would like to have a reference instead.

Comment: What I usually do to get around this is write a `SetB()`, `SetC()` methods in class `A`. That way you don't have ugly `if` conditions all over the place.

Comment: If you could explicitly call a setter property method `c(12)` the problem would be solved but I don't think that's possible either!

Comment: Well, yes, but is there any reason why you don't want to write two `Set()` methods? It's pretty simple and clean.

Comment: No it's not, C# hides the property getters/setters for you but the issue is the same with fields anyway, although they don't have setters

Comment: @Sach I personally wouldn't sacrifice c#'s syntactic sugar for properties to allow such statements

Comment: I guess it's a matter of preference. As long as you give the method the same access modifier as the property's, it doesn't break any rules. Personally I prefer having a nice clean method over doing `if(A!=null && B!=null){ A.B.C=12; }` everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @user2864740 wrote in his answer - the c# language doesn't support such a thing.
The most concise way you can write it in c# is probably this:

```
if (A?.B is null) A.B.C = 12;
```

However I find the need for such a null-safe property assignment rather strange - I mean, if you have the need to populate a property of some instance, surely you need that instance to actually be there - and if `B` or `A` are null at that point, your program should probably not simply ignore that and treat `A.B.C = 12;` as a NO-OP - but throw a `NullReferenceException`.

That being said, you don't want to see a `NullReferenceException` being thrown in a production code, but rather write your code in such a way that it would be null safe.

IMHO, The way to handle such cases is not by avoiding the value assignment to the property - but by making sure that the reference that holds this property is actually not null before attempting to populate the property.

Comment: That's quite a nice option. I largely agree that this is a bit of an edge case but on the other hand the `?.` operator exists for just this sort of reason - if nothing else your solution would allow a single test not multiple nested checks.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that some edge cases probably exists that requires such a construct.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to use operators like ?. and ?? to safely handle the case that a or b [on the LHS of an assignment] is null..

No, there is no syntax to get the same short-hand bypass effect for an assignment. Such has not been added to the language.

In the current form, only ever evaluating to a value, it would be more comparable to a compiler error similar to:

```
(a.b.c) = 12; // LHS is a ‘value’
```

However, a?.b?.. merely expands internally to an equivalent chain of conditions, and *if* defined/implemented, this could also apply to such a hypothetical case. Anyway, can still be done manually in the presented question.